# What is the equivalent function of fileChooserDialogNew with gi-gtk

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2hs

I'm making a GTK interface with `gi-gtk` for a Haskell program and I would like to create a dialog to seek for files. In the `gtk2hs`, there was a function called `fileChooserDialogNew` which was creating this kind a dialog but I didn't find an equivalent function with `gi-gtk`.

What is the correct way to create a such dialog with `gi-gtk` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you write `new FileChooserDialog []`, though I don't have an install lying around to test right now. The third argument lets you set initial values for properties.

See [the documentation](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi) for some discussion of what to put in `[]`, and maybe the haddocks for [`new`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-gi-base-0.26.0/docs/Data-GI-Base.html), though I personally found the latter only mildly enlightening.